Can my conditional format ignore a cell that displays blank until the data for the formula is complete?
I have an Excel spreadsheet that requires users to fill in columns B & C with dates.
Column D uses a formula to calculate business days including holidays =NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2$J$:$J$17).
Column E uses a formula to determine if the business days are less or equal to 2 business day =IF((D2<=2),"Yes","No") and I also have conditional formatting set to change the color of the cell in column E (Yes = green, No = red).
I have the spreadsheet to display any cells with a value of zero as blank.
What I am hoping to achieve, is for column E not to display an answer or conditional formatting until columns B & C have been completed to trigger the formula in D to calculate.  Is this even possible?  Some of my answers in column D may continue to be zero but I only want the formula and conditional formatting in column E to populate once the information has been completed in columns B & C.
I am using Microsoft 365 for enterprise MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20550) 64-bit[text]
I have tried to put multiple formulas in cell E and I have also tried additional conditional formatting that the conditions would stop if the value was blank or zero first.

Why not add that logic to your conditional format formula then? IF(or( B2<>"", C2<>""),...  So that if either of those two cells are empty it will still return a FALSE

I am very new to all of this (self teaching by internet). What exactly would the entire formula look like in this instance?
I have tried adding it to the formula in the cell and get an error that the formula isn't correct and when I try to create a new conditional format rule... it doesn't do anything.  I have tried copying exactly what you have into a new conditional format rule and setting it to stop if true and it is the first rule, but it does not leave the cell blank as intended.

You have to format your cell to appear blank: no background/white colour, and white font, or whatever matching background and font colour you like. This way there will still be something in the cell, but it just won't show. Or you could include it in front of your formula in column D, so that it just doesn't calculate.

@CLaFollette to my previous note, you're creating a rule that does something when a condition is fulfilled in B & C, it may look like if(B1>1,"Yes",""), but you can add multiple conditions using AND or OR, the distinction being do both conditions need to be TRUE to get the result you want or not. So i would create a rule that looks like =if( or( b2="",c2="") to start and if this is true to essentially skip whatever logic it would've done. and if it's false then do the if statement you were doing originally.

Thank you so much!  I got it working!  I truly appreciate all your help.
